# XSLT: Sum of all previous attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I am having some troubling getting summing up the arraySize attribute numbers pertaining to each element.

XML CODE:

```
<head>
    <element>
        <message name="something">
            <field arraySize="1"/>
            <struct name="asdf">
                <struct name="qwera">
                    <field arraySize="1"/>
                    <field arraySize="1"/>                
                </struct>
                <struct name="xcv">
                    <field arraySize="3"/>
                    <field arraySize="1"/>
                </struct>
                <struct name="nnge">
                    <struct name="sdfssk">
                        <field arraySize="1"/>
                        <field arraySize="1"/>                
                    </struct>
                    <struct name="fhjmn">
                        <field arraySize="2"/>
                        <field arraySize="1"/>
                    </struct>
                    <struct name="wetryk">
                        <field arraySize="1"/>
                        <field arraySize="1"/>
                    </struct>
                </struct>
            </struct>
            <field arraySize="1"/>
        </message>
    </element>
    <element>
       ... similar struct "tree"
    </element>
    <element>
       ... similar struct "tree"
    </element>
</head>
```

XSLT code: This is how I've tried to solve the problem.

```
<xsl:template match="p:struct">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="sum(preceding-sibling::*//@arraySize)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:field">
    <xsl:param name="previous" select="0"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$previous + sum(preceding-sibling::*//@arraySize)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
element #1
1   
2
3
6
7
8   
9
11
12 
13 
14
15

element #2
1
2
... etc
```

Actual output:

```
1   <-- Problem #1
1
2
5
6
1   <--- Problem #2
2 
4
5
6
7
15  <-- The correct summation is produced here.
```

I need to sum all of the preseding arraySize attributes. It works somewhat, but the two problems are: 1. the first field isn't summed. 2. The summation restarts at the third indented struct (if indented is the correct terminology).

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show the output you actually expect in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot about that. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I think you should be using the `preceding::` axis and not the `preceding-sibling::` axis.

Like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:p="aaa">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="nl" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p:element" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p:element">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('element #', position(), $nl)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p:field">
    <xsl:variable name="elId" select="generate-id(ancestor::p:element)" />
    <xsl:variable name="preds"
                  select="preceding::*/@arraySize[generate-id(ancestor::p:element) = 
                                                  $elId]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@arraySize + sum($preds), $nl)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the output:

```
element #1
1
2
3
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15

element #2
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I just noticed I made a rather significant mistake in omitting some details. There are more than one element nodes and it should only sum up the attributes inside itself. I apologise and hope you can still offer some assistance.

Comment: @user3010546 But now your XML source is missing a root element, so it's not valid.

Comment: Thank you very, VERY much that fixed it :) been staring at this for hours, and now that I see the solution it seems so simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="head/element">
    <xsl:variable name="elementID" select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('element #', position(), '&#10;' )"/>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//field">
        <xsl:value-of select="@arraySize + sum(preceding::field[generate-id(ancestor::element)=$elementID]/@arraySize)" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```